# How do I parse linked lists elements in a way that i can use them to execute a command

Tags: c, linked-list, exec, bison

I am trying to develop my own shell using C, Bison and Flex. All the bison and flex code work, my problem is with the linked lists. I should be able to get the arguments recognized by the bison code and parse them to the execvp() so I can execute the command I want. How do I do that? Do I need to parse them as a string?

Note: I'm not using arguments since I'm trying to call the execvp() inside another function.

Input is like this:

```
 ./interpretador

  mostra file
```

Where "mostra" the program I want to execute and "file" is the file as second parameter

The code that executes the command:

```
  case MOSTRA:
            {

            pid = fork();

            printf("\nPID: %d\n", pid);

            if (pid == 0)
            {
                    printf("\nDone.\n ");

            /*What I'm trying to do*/

            if (execvp(lst->type, lst->arg1) == -1)
            {
                  perror("\nErro no Exec\n");
            }

            //printf("\nexecutou\n");

            exit (1);

            } else if (pid < 0)
            {
                    perror ("\nErro!");

                    exit(1);
            }else
            {
                    while (wait(&estado) != pid);
            }

        }
        break;
```

The linked list:

```
command *mostra(command *lst, Value* path)
 {
    command *node = (command*) malloc(sizeof(command));
    node->type = MOSTRA;
    node->arg1 = path;
    node->next = lst;
    node->subCommands = NULL;
    return node;

    //printf("cheguei aqui");
 }
```

The linked List for the shell:

```
Interpretador *new_interpretador()
{   
    Interpretador *interpretador = (Interpretador*) malloc(sizeof(Interpretador));
    interpretador-> vars = NULL; // no variables in the beginning

    return interpretador;
}
```

the bison code:

```
 program : commandList { Launch($1); };

 commandList 
 : command              { $$ = $1; }
 | command commandList  { $1->next = $2; $$ = $1; }
 ;

 command  
 : MT VAR_VALUE        { $$ = mostra ( NULL, $2 ); }
 | AP VAR_VALUE        { $$ = apaga ( NULL, $2); }
 | AC NAME VAR_VALUE   { $$ = acrescenta ( NULL, $2, $3); }
 | MAKE VAR_NAME value { $$ = insert_Make (NULL, $2, $3); } 
 ;

 value: INT       { /*$$ = new_int_value($1);*/ }
 | NAME      { $$ = new_name($1); }
 | VAR_VALUE { $$ = new_var_value($1); }
 ;



 %%

 int yyerror(char* msg) {
 printf("ERROR: %s\n", msg);
 return 0;
 }
```

the flex code:

```
%%

make            { return MAKE; }

mostra|mt       { return MT; }

[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+ { yylval.str = strdup(yytext); return VAR_VALUE; }

\$[a-z]+        { /*return VAR_NAME;*/}

[ \n\r\t]       { /* ignore */ }

.               { return yytext[0]; }

%%

int yywrap() { return 1; }
```

Answer (score 1):

`execvp` does not know anything about your linked list implementation. It also doesn't know anything about your enum values, like `MOSTRA`.

It is expecting two arguments. The first is the name of an executable, to be searched for in `$PATH`, or the absolute path to the executable. The second argument is an array of character strings, where the first element in the array is the name of the program, the arguments start at the second element, and the last element is `NULL`.

In other words, you need to construct (from your linked list) an array that would look like this:

```
char* argv = {"mostra", "file", NULL};
```

so that you could call `execvp` like this:

```
if (execvp(argv[0], argv) == -1)
```

---

Note: If `execvp` returns there was an error, regardless of what the return value was. A successful call to `execvp` does not return.